# Not able to read some json files where they are downloaded and saved via url in ios7

Tags: json, ios7, xcode5

Im having issues with this code reading some .json files, it works fine on json that can be read via IE like a webpage but wont work on files that the url is tring to download them like a ftp style.

In the end im looking at populating labels with the json info once this works but cant see what around the URLRequest is causing it.

This is what code im testing it with:

```
//  WDViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WDViewController : UIViewController{
    NSArray *jsonArray;
    NSMutableData *data;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *outputLabel;

-(IBAction)WDPlayerButtonUpdate:(id)sender;
@end

//  WDViewController.m
#import "WDViewController.h"

@interface WDViewController ()

@end

@implementation WDViewController

@synthesize outputLabel;

-(IBAction)WDPlayerButtonUpdate:(id)sender{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://gooruism.com/feed/json"];
    NSURLRequest *data = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData{
    [data appendData:theData];
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];

        // Loop through jsonArray
    for (int i = 0; i< jsonArray.count; i++)
        {
        outputLabel.text = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"889"]; // Set Labels
        }
}    
@end
```

The json file and url are just one that I found looking for a solution via Google and are only for testing.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot more Google and learning some more about json,
Ive got the code working.

Ended up being more of a null exemption from empty indexes and not calling objectForKeys correctly, as was leaving strings that errored when then using to populate a label.

Code I finally got to work:

```
//
//  WDViewController.m
//  JSON Test

#import "WDViewController.h"

@interface WDViewController ()

@end

@implementation WDViewController

@synthesize testLabel;

-(IBAction)WDPlayerButtonUpdate:(id)sender
{
        // Set network activity indicator
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

        // Set json url.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"<url for json>"];

        // get the url page into the nsdata object.
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        // Read json (from jasondata) and convert to object.
    if ( jsonData != nil)
        {
        NSError *error = nil;
        id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

        if (error == nil)
            NSLog (@"%@", result);

        NSLog(@"Test 1");
            // Retrieve array and show in log
        NSLog(@"From status index: %@", [result objectForKey:@"status"]);

            // Retrieve data and log
        NSLog(@"From profile.handle index: %@", [[result objectForKey:@"profile"]objectForKey:@"handle"]);

        NSLog(@"Next Test 2"); // Populate label with data handle
        yestLabel.text = [[result objectForKey:@"profile"]objectForKey:@"handle"];

        NSLog(@"End of Tests");
        }
}
@end
```